# Blinking LED on Sparkfun Thing ESP8266

Tags: arduino

So I'm brand new to programming with dev boards, and I need a more experienced pair of eyes to check my hardware setup. I've added the "Sparkfun ESP8266 Thing Dev" to Tools inside of the Arduino IDE, and I believe the code written is correct as well. What should I change with my cable and board setup to get the simple blink program running?

Code:

```
//pin 5
  //int ESP8266_LED = 13;

  //#define led 5

  int led = 5;
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:


  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);

  //ESP8266_LED
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH); // LED off
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(led, LOW); // LED on
  delay(500);


}
```

UPDATED Board:

[This is where I'm at now after a few helpful suggestions...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhQbs.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resistor is not in the correct row. You need to put the resistor and the red cable in the same row.
Also don't forget to have a wire to your ground pin.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the red cable has one point that stands by the 5 pin, the other end of it must also remain in the same row. Next to that second end, the resistor must keep both ends in the same row as well? (so both ends of red cable and resistor all in one row)

Comment: The other end of the red cable can go anywhere. However your resistor must be in the same row as the end of the red cable.   I hope this drawing will help http://i.imgur.com/qmrE0rt.png

Comment: That drawing was very helpful, thank you. In your drawing and other walkthroughs, the cables literally attach at the pin. In other drawings, there are those black rectangular arrays (I believe are called female headers) that have holes at the top where cables can plug into. Is this required? Or should I be able to get by with the cable sitting right outside the 5 pin like I currently have? Right now this board has pointed things where the pins are located.

Comment: You can get by with the cable sitting right outside the pin 5. That's because when pin 5 is turned ON, the row that pin 5 is located in the breadboard will also be ON. Because the pins are already connected to the breadboard. If you board had female headers like this: http://i.imgur.com/bgJhzXl.jpg  you would have to connect a male to male cable from the board to the breadboard.

Comment: That makes so much more sense! Thank you very much. The LED should have the positive (longer?) end closest to the resistor, right? And then the shorter, negative end follows along to the ground cable. I'll keep tinkering around until I get it right, but you've been a ton of help.